# Parsing a .sis (symbian) file using java

Tags: java, symbian

Im looking to read a .sis file (symbian content) using java, and hopefully try to derive as much meta related information from the binary as possible, such as application name, version, platform support and target languages. I think this can be done from looking at the symbian spec, and I seem to remember another application that did this, but wasnt quite sure how? Does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two, slightly different SIS file formats. The old one for Symbian OS versions prior to 9.x and another with platform security additions for 9.x and later. I assume you want to decode this newer format.

Here's a link to the [SIS file specification for 9.x and later](http://developer.symbian.com/main/downloads/papers/SymbianOSv91/softwareinstallsis.pdf).

For a code sample on parsing 9.x SIS files, have a look at [sisinfo.py](http://www.niksula.cs.hut.fi/~jpsukane/sisinfo.html).

Comment: Thanks. Using the specfication as reference, I have ported the sysinfo python script into java. Seems to work well, havnt yet added support for certificates etc, have made it pluggable per sis field, so support can be expanded in slow time. Im surprised this hasnt already been done in Java, so im contemplating open sourcing it.